# My variable is successfully displayed for the user but my sql query cant see it

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

I am trying to get my program to take the posted id and use it to update other fields in my database and when I echo the variable out it works fine, however if I echo my sql string its not there

```
    <body class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="amount"><?php echo $id; ?></label>
          <input type="number" name ="amount" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Hvað viltu hækka/lækka um marga kassa?">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="plus" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" name="minus" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </form>
</body>
```

php code

```
require_once("include/header.php");
require_once("include/mysqliConn.php");
$id = $_POST['number'];
$orginal = $_POST['magn'];
if(isset($_POST['plus'])){
  $amount = $_POST['amount'];
  $finalAmount = $orginal+$amount;
  $sql = 'UPDATE stada SET Magn="'.$finalAmount.'", lastModified="Aron DC" WHERE Nr="'.$id.'"';
  echo $sql;
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

  $conn->close();
}
if(isset($_POST['minus'])){
  if ($orginal>$amount) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $finalAmount = $orginal-$amount;
    $sql = 'UPDATE stada SET Magn="'.$finalAmount.'", lastModified="Aron DC" WHERE Nr="'.$id.'"';

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
  }else{
    echo '<script>alert("Þú getur ekki tekið fleiri kassa en eru til á lager");</script>';
  }

}
```

here is a picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE8Dy.png)

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.